# Horizontal scrollbar disappears using AutoSizeMode property

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, scrollbar

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I have a DatagridView which contains four columns. I need:

to display the horizontal scrollbar in order to see all these columns and
to display the last column so that it fills my datagridview
To display the horizontal scrollbar I've set the ScrollBar property to Horizontal and used this code:

```
 _formMain.GridCol_Name.Frozen = true;
 _formMain.GridCol_Info.Frozen = true;
 _formMain.DataCol_Position.Frozen = false;
 _formMain.GridCol_Visibility.Frozen = true;
```

To show the last column so that it fills the remaining space in DatagridView I have used this code:

```
 _formMain.Grid_NonAnatObj.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;       
 _formMain.GridCol_Info.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

The problem is that the second code sample "removes" the horizontal trackbar.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: winforms, unfortunately :)

Comment: Check every single data coloumn and make sure frozen is set to false because if 1 is true then it  won't work in the layout property

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

The width available for fill mode is determined by subtracting the widths of all other columns from the width of the client area of the control. If this width is smaller than the combined MinimumWidth values of all fill-mode columns, the horizontal scroll bar is displayed, all fill-mode columns are shown with their minimum widths, and user column-resizing is disabled.

Try tweaking your MinimumWidth of the columns

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work but it's an interesting observation. I've posted a new question after some code changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863788/horizontal-scrollbar-disappear-setting-the-last-column-size-to-fill