# Metro Datagridview Column width

Tags: winforms, datagridview, microsoft-metro, datagridviewcolumn

When I set the `AutoSizeColumnsMode = Fill` the width of columns covers all area and don't find scroll bar at bottom. But, when I set it as `AutoSizeColumnsMode = None` then the columns width shrinks.

So, my requirements are:
All space in datagridview should be filled. (should cover all area)
When there is more column, there should appear scroll bar. So, it gives better look. Is there any event or property which I can use ???

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27870091/3773066) at an answer I gave to a similar question. The idea is to use `Fill` if the `Auto`/set widths leave empty grid space, otherwise use `Auto`/set widths.

Comment: Metro gridview have diff properties...

Comment: Is it not [this MetroStyle DataGridView](http://denricdenise.info/2014/09/metrostyle-datagridview/)? Because that just inherits from DataGridView, so all common properties are still available.

Comment: Yea!!! Thanks a lot...