# C#: Fill the width of DataGridView field AND add a scroll bar when needed

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

I am working on a form application in C#, and I have been stuck with the width of `DataGridView`.
What I want to achieve is:

1. Fill the `DataGridView` horizontal field completely with the data by appropriately adjusting the column sizes, **AND**
2. Add a scroll bar if more space is needed for more columns.

The problem is, I am not sure how many columns exist in the table to read data from.
I thought I have achieved requirement 1 and 2 with the following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<myDataGridView.Columns.Count; i++){
    myDataGridView.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

However, I realized that this does not satisfy requirement 2. Where there is more column space needed, it fails to add a scroll bar. If there are more columns than a certain value, it hides some part of the columns and data cells. As you can see in the image below, the relationship column's *"p"* is hidden **AND** there is no scroll bar: [image]

After some struggle, I noticed the following code succeeds in adding the scroll bar:

```
for(int i=0; i<myDataGridView.Columns.Count; i++){
    myDataGridView.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
}
```

However, this code now does not satisfy my first requirement. It does add a scroll bar if more space for more columns is needed, but if there are only a few columns it leaves the unused area like the image below (the backcolor is black):
[image]

Now I am at a loss on how to achieve both requirements. One way satisfies only one requirement. Can someone please give me some advance on how to meet both requirements? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontal scrollbar disappear setting the last column size to fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863788/horizontal-scrollbar-disappear-setting-the-last-column-size-to-fill)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the fillweight of each column and set their autosizemode to `Fill`, and set their min width so they are not just forced to fit regardless of how many columns you have or how narrow the user makes the window.

```
    myDataGridView.Columns[i].FillWeight = GetFillWeight(myDataGridView.Columns[i].Name);
    myDataGridView.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    myDataGridView.Columns[i].MinimumWidth = (int) myDataGridView.Columns[i].FillWeight;
```

If you set the minimum width of the columns, and those add up to more than the width of the gridview, then the gridview will get a scrollbar.

I suggest to set the FillWeight, you have a function that actually sets it differently depending on what column it is.  Something like

```
    private float GetFillWeight(string FieldName)
    {
        switch (FieldName)
        {
            case "FirstName":
            case "LastName":
            case "City":
                return 300;
            case "Sex":
                return 150;
            case "Age":
                return 100;
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is NewCol on Line 3 in your sample program?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `myDataGridView.Colums[i]`