# Datagridview column width set

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview (c#, windows application), which is just a data table  bound.

User will select number of rows and columns to generate the table layout.

Now what I want is regardless of the amount of columns, the column width should be the same and the columnheader (the numbering from 1...n) should be visible.

What happens is that the columns are shrinking if more number of columns are given.

Please help out.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news; however, I am confident you will have to implement this yourself. I am assuming the grids `AutoSizeColumnMode` is set to `Fill`… unfortunately, the grid does not care how “wide” the columns are and will obligingly stuff 100 columns into a small size grid. Given this, it is clear as you have seen, that maintaining a “minimum” width for each column is something “your” code is going to have to do.

Comment: You can either create a minimum size for each column width or use a horizontal scroll bar. IMHO, if the user is creating the number of columns, this is going to be an inevitability that your code is going to have to manage as you have seen. I guess my question is… if the user asks for too many columns to display them properly in the grid… what are you going to do? You are going to have to make a decision to either make the grid wider or add a horizontal scroll bar. Those are about your only options.

Comment: I answered a similar question in reference to this, it may help… [C#: DataGridView's extra space on right-hand side and scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777399/c-datagridviews-extra-space-on-right-hand-side-and-scrollbar/46785979#46785979) … Good Luck!